# loading website in sequence with java script

Tags: javascript

I need a JS to display websites in sequence within certain time interval. In the code below, I want it to first display google for Xms, than NPR for Xms so on. How can I accomplish that

```
    window.open("https://www.google.com","_self");
    // wait Xms
    window.open("http://www.npr.org","_self");
    // wait Xms
    window.open("https://www.washingtonpost.com","_self");
    // wait Xms
    window.open("https://www.google.com","_self");
    // wait Xms
```

Comment: Looks like a job for a `promise` or `callback`

Comment: Check out [setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout)

Comment: You'll probably need to frame them. Once you navigate away from your page, your JavaScript will stop running, so you have to display those pages as part of your site. In HTML5, each site can disallow that though.

Answer (score 0):

```
var interval=2*1000; // 2 seconds
["https://www.google.com","http://www.npr.org","https://www.washingtonpost.com",
"https://www.google.com"].forEach((url,i)=>{
       setTimeout(()=>{
              window.open(url,'_self');
       },interval*i);
})
```

## Explain :

- 1st url will be opened immediatly    : `interval * 0 = 0`
- 2nd URL will be opened after 2 sec   : `interval * 1 = 2000`
- 3rd URL will be opened after 4 sec   : `interval * 2 = 4000`
- ....

Comment: nope if it is _self it will only open the first url

Comment: You are right. _self indeed only load the first url, but I wish you would provide a solution, not the half answer.

Comment: @Abdennour TOUMI Thank you for your code. It works somewhat, however, what I really want is for the browser to display a site for X amount of time, that automatically moves onto the next site without any user intervention. The current code, I have to click on the back button only then the next site will load up.